# Resizable WPF Grid inserts blank lines between rows and columns depending on actual size

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, resize

I have a `Grid` displaying rectangles. The `Grid` can be resized and is supposed to display adjacent rectangles without any gap.

However, depending on the actual size of the `Grid`, blank lines appear between the rows and columns of the `Grid`. I guess this is to make up for sizes where the width isn't a multiple of the number of columns, or the height isn't a multiple of the number of rows.

The following XAML code demonstrates this:

```
<Window x:Class="test.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="DarkBlue"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Fill="DarkOrange"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkBlue"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkBlue"></Rectangle>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

How can I prevent those blank lines? If one or some of the columns/rows are slightly larger than others is not really a problem. I'd like to keep the markup simple.

I unsuccessfully tried `Stretch`, `Fill`, putting the `Grid` in a `ViewBox`, `ShowGridLines=False, Width=Auto`, etc.

An image of the issue is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` to your `Grid` control

[Pixel Snapping in WPF Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx)